# Iteratively adding up first and last numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write a function that continually adds together the first and last elements of an array using forEach with array.shift() + array.pop().

The problem is that the for-loop doesn't complete the innermost numbers, and so the array is always left with 2 values inside of it.

**Code:**

```
function choreAssignment(chores) {
  chores.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b});
  var assignment = [];
  chores.forEach(function() {
  assignment.push((chores.pop() + chores.shift()));
});
  return assignment.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b});
}
```

The above code works as expected, but it leaves the innermost two values inside the `chores` array.

For example if I run:

**Code:**

```
var arr = [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 9, 4, 3];
choreAssignment(arr);
```

I get:

```
[8, 9, 10]
```

Ie, it adds 9 & 1, 7 & 2, 5 & 3, but it leaves [4, 4] inside the array.

I'm not sure why this is. Thank you.

Comment: Your example and description do not seem to match up. I would expect the output to be `[4, 8, 16, 7]` for the sample input `[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 9, 4, 3]`.

Comment: It first sorts the chores algorithm from smallest value to largest.  So before it uses >shift() and pop() the values are  listed as[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 9] so it adds together 9+1, 7+2, and 5+3, but not 4+4 for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the forEach to:

```
while (chores.length) {
    assignment.push((chores.pop() + chores.shift()));
}
```

Note this assumes there are always an even number of elements in array

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  Could you elaborate on why this method worked but forEach didn't?  I don't see why one would work and not the other.

Comment: @JonathanBechtel It's usually a bad idea to remove elements from an array while you are iterating over it.

Comment: @pzp thank you for the feedback. I was thinking of using reduce but wasn't connecting the dots for it so I went with this method instead.  This isn't going to be used in production, it's just kicking the tires.